# Add images in a view and convert view into jpeg image in ios

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

```
-(void)drawJPEG
{
    NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:nil options:nil];

    UIView* mainView = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

    for (UIView* view in [mainView subviews]) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            UIImage* PassportSizePhoto = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpeg"];
            [self drawImage:PassportSizePhoto inRect:view.frame];
        }
    }
    UIImage *image;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainView.bounds.size);
    {
        [mainView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: What is your problem here?

Comment: why you are using jpeg image can you pleas explain the issue

Answer (score -1):

Please do not look forward to achieve already baked code from indirect utilization of hard earned expertise of others here.

Kindly give yourself some time to read the documentation of Apple about images.

1. Read about `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` in Apple docs.
2. Search `Stack-overflow` for resizing the image into required size.

This is a very simple stuff and asked million times on stack-overflow .